# Timer method not firing

Tags: c#, timer, console

I am using the following code to print a message to the console every 5 minutes but its, but the `Timer` doesn't seam to be firing.  What is wrong?

I want to call the MyMethod() after every 10 seconds but it calls only once

```
    using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace ThreadProgram
{
    class Program
    {
        private static System.Threading.Timer timer = new System.Threading.Timer((e) =>
        {
            MyMethod();
        }, null, 0, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10).Milliseconds);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("----Calling my method----");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void MyMethod()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("*** Method is executed at {0} ***", DateTime.Now);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your suggestion

Comment: You should start the timer at some point. Put `timer.Start()` in your main method.

Comment: For simplicity, try having your timer fire every 5 seconds instead of every 5 minutes so you aren't waiting for so long.

Comment: timer is not accessible inside the main() and MyMethod() is also not accessible in timer

Comment: Why people are down-voting this question? This site is for learning and the fact that this question has a simple answer doesn't mean its a bad one.

Comment: @Eli not my DV, but the tooltip for the downvote button does say *this question does not show any research effort* - which this question does not

Comment: @Default Research effort is most important. But if you need some help because you can't see the problem (especially when are a newbie - and the problem is dam too simple) I thing this is the place to ask

Comment: i tried sir but actually i first time working on the thread i am new to threading please suggest me the corrections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to enable as well as start your timer as shown below :-

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("----Calling my method----");
            timer.Start();
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
```

I just debugged your code it requires your MyMethod to be static else it will not even compile

and signature of the Timer is wrong as TotalMiliseconds returns double and it reuires int so better try below code using .Milliseconds + `make your timer static` else it would not be accessible in Main method :-

```
 private static System.Threading.Timer timer = new System.Threading.Timer((e) =>
        {
            MyMethod();
        }, null, 0, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5).Milliseconds);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems with this code. First is the timer not being started.

Make a call to `timer.Start();` in your main-method.

But there is another problem, as your code doesn't even compile. You are trying to call `MyMethod` from the timer; but this isn't possible as MyMethod isn't static.

Your code would change to the following:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     Console.WriteLine("----Calling my method----");
     timer.Start();
     Console.ReadLine();
}

private static void MyMethod()
{
    Console.WriteLine("*** Method is executed at {0} ***", DateTime.Now);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Last, the signature of the timer is wrong. It should be a static timer, and also the last parameter of the timer, period, requires an integer. `Timespan.TotalMiliseconds` returns a double so you are better off with `.Miliseconds`:

```
private static System.Threading.Timer timer = new System.Threading.Timer(state => MyMethod(), null, 0, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5).Milliseconds);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
{
  static Timer timer = new Timer(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5).Milliseconds);

  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("----Calling my method----");
    timer.AutoReset = true;
    timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
    timer.Start();
    Console.ReadLine();
  }

  static void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
  {
    MyMethod();
  }

  private static void MyMethod()
  {
    Console.WriteLine("*** Method is executed at {0} ***", DateTime.Now);
    Console.ReadLine();
  }
}
```

Try this

```
using Timer = System.Timers.Timer;
```

Answer (score 0):

Friends i got my answer but thanks to all of you for valuable suggestion
changes that i made in my program are as follows which may be useful for future references

```
static System.Threading.Timer timer = new System.Threading.Timer((e) =>
        {
            MyMethod();
        }, null, 0, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20).Seconds);
```

Once again thanks to all